# How can I loosely replicate this photoshop effect (formula)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, filter

Consider the following image:

[image]

I am using photopea online, but I think it is the same as photoshop. I attempt using the "Hue/Saturation" Adjustment layer, and when changing the hue property, get the following result:

[image]

I am looking for a formula to create this type of effect, as I need to do it dynamically for many images. However, anything I have found online regarding hue adjustment seems to adjust the 'h' in correlate with the following image, which can be found using the same 'hue' value, but checking the 'colorize' box:

[image]

What does the colorize box change, and how can I replicate the effect of the first adjusted image? Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why do you need a formula? In Photoshop you can just record the edit as an Action, and apply it to a batch of images using File > Automate > Batch.  Note if you use the colourise option, it essentially colourizes a monochrome (black and white) version of the image. Don't do that if it's not what you want.

Comment: If you are trying to do this with other software, ImageMagick which is a command line tool, has a -modulate operator which can rotate the hue of an image.  I'm not familiar enough with it to give you an example unfortunately but [see here for more info](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate)

Answer (score 2):

Colorize takes from the original image only the brightness variations. Hue and saturation are determined by the sliders. Leave colorize unchecked and you can shift the hue and saturation as you did in your 2nd image. The lightness slider affects in the same way, no matter is the colorize mode ON or OFF.

You can use Image > Adjustment > Hue/Saturation with hue shift +89 to get the shown effect without inserting an adjustment layer. It can be recorded into an action to apply the same to several images. Learn how to use actions to repeat a set of adjustments for a folder of images.

[image]

**Not asked:** Full white and black do not take color when one applies colorize. You must reduce contrast to make them grey. That's a limitation of the RGB color system.

If you are after more ways to get weird color changes you can try to mangle the R,G and B curves separately after opening Image > Adjustment > Curves:

[image]

The result is surely difficult to predict, but generally it reduces contrast. You can later increase contrast or saturation to make it bright again.

As a third method you can try Gradient map. It's is a popular way to change the brightness scale to a predefined series of colors:

[image]

**Using adjustment layers** for searching a good effect is recommended. The image below them stays intact and it can be changed. And you can save them for future use if you save the image as PSD.